# Why is .hgignore being ignored?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am very new to Hg so please excuse my ignorance here...

I am using Mercurial and TortoiseHg in Windows 7. I have a repository created that has the following folder structure:

```
-- My repo dir
|
|--- .hg
|--- .hgignore
|--- File 1
|--- File 2
|--- ...
```

My database data files live in the repo directory but I do not want them to be included as part of the repository. I've tried all kinds of things in the `.hgignore` file, but regardless when I right-click on the repo folder in the Windows Shell and go to `Hg Commit...`, it includes the two database data files in the list of files to be committed. Yes, I can uncheck them manually, but my thought was that by being in `.hgignore` they wouldn't be included in the list of files to commit.

Here's my current incarnation of `.hgignore`, although I've tried a handful of others with no luck:

```
MyDatabase\.mdf
MyDatabase\_log\.ldf
```

Am I being daft here, or is it that TortoiseHg does not respect/inspect the `.hgignore` file when committing?

#### UPDATE:

Finally got this to work. I had to instruct Mercurial to forget the files, as @Diego suggested. Interestingly, though, when I followed @Diego's suggestions and tried to forget them via the command-line it did not work. I had to go to Windows Explorer, right-click on the files, and from the context menu I chose TortoiseHg --> Forget Files...

Thanks for the suggestions, everyone.

Comment: Did you already commit the files?  If so, you need to remove them from the repo first.

Comment: @sdolan: No, I did not commit them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe mercurial is already tracking those files. If files are already tracked then .hgignore does not have any effect. Try:

```
hg forget MyDatabase\.mdf MyDatabase\_log\.ldf
```

Then edit .hgignore to exclude those files and commit.

That should solve it.

Comment: I did not commit (or track) the two database files. I've been unchecking them from TortoiseHg when checking in each time. I tried running the command line you specified but it reports the files are not found.

Comment: I (finally) got this working, and I think your answer was along the right vein. I had to, from the Windows shell, right click on these two files and go to TortoiseHg --> Forget Files... Doing it from the command-line, like you suggested, didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this line at the beginning of your [.hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) file:

```
syntax: glob

MyDatabase\.mdf
MyDatabase\_log\.ldf
```

Comment: The files `MyDatabase\.mdf` and `MyDatabase\_log\.ldf` really exist? Perhaps you should use something like: `MyDatabase/*` and `MyDatabase/_log/*`

Answer (score 0):

Scott,
Do you have any other mdf/ldf files that you **want** to add to the repository? If not, could you just try the following in your `.hgignore` file?

```
syntax: glob
*.mdf
*.ldf
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. It seems as if TortoiseHg is ignoring my .hgignore file. :-(

Comment: @scott-mitchell, I just tried the following locally: `hg init; mkdir MyDatabase; echo > MyDatabase/spam.mdf; echo > MyDatabase/beans.mdf`; I then created `.hgignore` with the content in my note above and the output of `hg status` was `? .hgignore`; after `hg add .hgignore` `hg status` gave me `A .hgignore`; so far, Mercurial seemed to be ignoring the mdf and ldf files as expected; I fired up the TortoiseHg workbench from this directory and even Tortoisehg did not list either the mdf or ldf file. Let me know if anything I did differs from what you have

Comment: I did get it working by ignoring the file through TortoiseHg's context menu, but the command-line approach suggested by others didn't seem to work. I'm not sure why. I also tried creating a brand new repository and adding MDF and LDF files and trying your steps and TortoiseHg ignored them as expected. So I'm not sure what happened, but the good news is that I got it working! :-)